# How to create proper structure for Okhttp API call?

Tags: android, okhttp

I want to **create structure** of **okhttp** API Call. In my one of the application, i have to call api in every screen, so writting below okhttp call in each and every screen is inappropriate. Here is my code for api calling using okhttp:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("message", "Your message")
        .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("http://www.foo.bar/index.php")
        .post(formBody)
        .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    // Do something with the response.
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to create a single class to make API call.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you should look up how to use retrofit and dagger (or other DI) and the repository pattern, the API and Db and/or cache are held in the repository and the repository is injected into your viewmodel or activity, and you just tell your repository you want some data when you want it. The repository checks your db or your cache  and decides whether to make webcalls or not. That way your logic will not be on every screen

Comment: as mentioned above, use retrofit. Okhttp is a basic construct and should be used when you make some specific calls over http that cannot be handled by libraries like retrofit, otherwise you will have a lot of boilerplate code that will be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create AsynTask like
public class NetworkClientOkhttp extends AsyncTask {

```
private OkHttpClient client;
private OkHttpClient.Builder builder = null;

private String mUrl;
private String mParams;
private ResponseListener responseListener;

public NetworkClientOkhttp(String mUrl, String mParams, ResponseListener responseListener) {
    this.mUrl = mUrl;
    this.mParams = mParams;
    this.responseListener = responseListener;

    builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    builder.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    client = builder.build();
    this.execute();
}

public void sendRequest() {
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("params", mParams)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(mUrl)
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        String res = response.body().string();
        if (responseListener != null) {
            responseListener.onReceiveResponse(res);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void sendFormBodyRequest() {

    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(mParams);

        FormBody.Builder formBody = new FormBody.Builder();
        while (object.keys().hasNext()) {
            String keyName = object.keys().next();
            formBody.add(keyName, object.optString(keyName));
        }
        RequestBody requestBody = formBody.build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(mUrl)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        String res = response.body().string();
        if (responseListener != null) {
            responseListener.onReceiveResponse(res);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("params", mParams)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(mUrl)
            .header("issecuritydisable", "0")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        String res = response.body().string();
        return res;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
    super.onPostExecute(res);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(res)){
        if (responseListener != null) {
            responseListener.onReceiveResponse(res);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: no point in creating such things yourself, when libraries like retrofit already handle this and are secure at the same time.